# LEFT JOIN - List all sellers and their sales, including those who do not have sales

Tags: mysql, left-join

In the following example for demonstration I get the sum of sales value per seller, and I count sales, with the following query:

```
tab_sellers

id_seller | seller
   1         John
   2         Marie
   3         Jamie


tab_sales

id | sales | seller | value
1     BMW       1      100
2     FORD      1      200
3     FIAT      2      300
4     FORD      2      400


SELECT tsl.sellers, 
       SUM(ts.value) AS value_sales, 
       COUNT(ts.sales) AS sales_number
FROM tab_sellers tsl
LEFT JOIN tab_sales ts ON  tsl.id_seller = ts.seller
GROUP BY ts.seller
```

With this query I get a list of the sellers that make sales and the sum of their sales value and the number of sales.
In this case only a list with the sales of John and Marie appears.

However, what I want to get is a list of all sellers, whether or not they have sales, the sales number, and the total sales value.

That is, in the result should also appear Jamie with sales = 0 and value = 0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try check for if null

```
      SELECT tsl.sellers, 
             SUM(ifnull(ts.value,0)) AS value_sales, 
             COUNT(inull(ts.sales,0)) AS sales_number
      FROM tab_sellers tsl
      LEFT JOIN tab_sales ts ON  tsl.id_seller = ts.seller
      GROUP BY tsl.seller
```